# how to put a binary file in jasper sever

Tags: rest, binary, jasperserver

I'm searching to put a binary file like image or reportUnit to jasperServer using REST api.
I know how to put an utf8 file.

Thanks all

Comment: How did you do it with the utf8 file? Which docs are you referring to?

Comment: I use jasperServer-Library and you have a link [http://jasperserver-library.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html]

Comment: So... how do you handle the UTF8 file? Please [edit] your question with code.